# Is it possible to test different environments in the simulator?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Or via the google assistant on your devices?

Thus far in my development those are the primary ways I have been testing.

Currently I would like to keep a "stable" "test version" of the app available to people while simultaneously working on new features.

Is this possible?

In the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments?authuser=1) I only see how to test a different environment/version with curl.

Comment: Are you using Actions on Google and the AoG simulator? Or are you just using Dialogflow?

Comment: @Prisoner I'm using Actions for fulfillment.